# Java String output

Tags: java, string, replace, digit

My String input is String Number = "546+90".

I want to give output like this **"546 + 90"**.how can i do it in java? Right now I am trying:

```
Number.replaceAll("[0-9]"," ");
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Don't capitalize variable names

Comment: seems there is confusion whether the input is "String Number=546+90" or just "546+90"

Comment: I've made mistake.sorry!!!. its "546+90". i have edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `Number` is a built-in class in the `java.lang` package, so you should never use that name.

Second, variables should be written in lower-case, so it should be `number`.

Third, Strings are immutable, so the need to get the return value from `replaceAll()`.

If you want this string: `"String Number=546+90"`
to become this string: `"546 + 90"`
then you need to strip anything before `=` and add spaces around the `+`.

This can be done by chaining `replace` calls:

```
String number = "String Number=546+90";
number = number.replaceFirst(".*=", "")
               .replaceAll("\\+", " + ");
System.out.println(number);
```

If you want other operators too, use a character class. You have to capture the character to retain it in the replacement string, and you *must* put `-` first or last (or escape it).

```
number = number.replaceFirst(".*=", "")
               .replaceAll("([-+*/%])", " $1 ");
```

Comment: So that whichever operator character is matched will be retained. See [`Matcher.appendReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) for full description.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable so you need to get the string resultant of the replace method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number="546+90";
        number  = number.replaceAll("\\+" , " + ");

        System.out.println(number);
    }
```

Comment: isn't + reserved? maybe it needs an escape

Answer (score 0):

Adding an escape characters will solve your problem 
  String Number = "\"" + "546+90" + "\"";